# warning: type clash on default action: <symp> != <>

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer, lex

I faced this problen when I am trying to run .y file

`Phase2.y:119.10-26: warning: type clash on default action: <symp> != <>`

line 119 in .y file we have

`

```
factor : LPAREN exp RPAREN
       | INT_LITERAL {
            strcpy($$.type ,"int");
strcpy($$.name,"");
    
}
```

`

I saw simple explanation when I am trying to found something to help but not clear for me

any help?
thank you

......................................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That rule contains two productions. The first production does not have a semantic action, so the default action is used. The default action is `{ $$ = $1; }`

Bison tries to verify that the default action is correctly typed. In this case, `$$` is `factor`, which you have probably declared to be `%type <symp> factor`. `$1` is `LPAREN`, which you have presumably declared to be an untyped token (that is, a token with no semantic value). Both of those declarations are correct, but that means that `$$ = $1;` is nonsense; you can't assign `$$` from a non-value.

You probably meant to use the `expr` as the value of the first production. It's `$2`, since `expr` is the second symbol on the right-hand side of the production. (You can also write it as `$expr`, which might be more clear.)

So the rule should read:

```
factor : LPAREN exp RPAREN { $$ = $2; }
       | INT_LITERAL {
            strcpy($$.type ,"int");
            strcpy($$.name,"");   
         }
```

Except that the semantic action for the second production is ignoring the value of the `INT_LITERAL` token, which seems unlikely to be correct.